# Pass Decimal value in NumericUpdown in C# for windows application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008, numericupdown

nup_Test

this is my numericupdown box , this accepts Integer value like 100,200 etc but i need to get the value like 12.45 etc .. Please help me how to obtain this Result.
Im working on C# application in visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 2):

NumericUpDown control has `DecimalPlaces` property as well as `Increment`.
From your example I can assume that you want `DecimalPlaces` to be equal `2` and `Increment` to be equal `0,05`.

Comment: DecimalPlaces not accepting in my application its giving an error

Comment: Error 19 'System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown' does not contain a definition for 'DecimalPlaces' and no extension method 'DecimalPlaces' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\projects\CEAT_3791415\softwares\SOURCE\MOBILE DEVICE\BTS_R12\BTS\BTS\frm_Master.cs 3038 30 BTS

Comment: i have added system.windows.forms dll but still i get this error